# Kuka youBot melodic ros installation

Tags: ros, kuka

I'm wondering if one can install Kuka youBot (i.e. the simulation part not the real hardware) in melodic ros. It seems there is no `melodic-devel` when I try to clone it from their [github](https://github.com/mas-group/youbot_simulation). When I try it  with `kinetic-devel`, I get this error

```
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Could NOT find brics_actuator (missing: brics_actuator_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'brics_actuator'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "brics_actuator"
  with any of the following names:

    brics_actuatorConfig.cmake
    brics_actuator-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "brics_actuator" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "brics_actuator_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "brics_actuator" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  youbot_simulation/youbot_gazebo_control/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/xxxx/Desktop/youBot/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/xxxx/Desktop/youBot/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:338: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I've cloned `[mas-group/youbot_description][2]` and `[mas-group/youbot_simulation][1]` in `catkin_ws/src` and run `catkin_make`. It seems the drivers need to be installed but they are for older ros versions. Any suggestions? OS is ubuntu 18.04 and melodic ROS, Gazebo 9.

Comment: `CMake Error: could not find the required component` what component can it not find?

Comment: Please provide enough context to be able to reproduce your problem. It's important to know what else you have installed and where since the error is about missing dependencies.  Also please provide the full output of the console including your error. You've missed the most important part of the referenced component the error in your question summary.

Comment: @Chuck and Tully sorry for the little details. Please see the update.

Comment: Well, the full error message tells you to install `brics_actuator`: `If
  "brics_actuator" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.` Looks like [the package is available here](http://wiki.ros.org/brics_actuator) but also looks like you fixed it yourself shortly after updating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by installing
`sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-brics-actuator`